# Dividing dataset on 2 stratified parts

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataset

I need to divide the dataset into 2 parts stratified by the values of one categorical column. That being said, the sklearn.model_selection tools are not suitable as they create 4 parts. Can I do it with pandas or something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
X_train, X_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, stratify='column_name')
```

Comment: Get an error:  "Singleton array array('model', dtype='<U5') cannot be considered a valid collection."

Comment: for this:  X_train, X_test = train_test_split(df, stratify='model')

Comment: nevertheless it made a split as required, Thank you!